# How can I convert this if else statement into ternary operator?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

I have a piece of code and I want to convert it to ternary operator. Can anyone help? It has 1 if and 2 else if conditions so I am having trouble converting it. Here is my code.

```
if ($this->session->data['desired_service']==1){
    echo 'Home Delivery';
} else if ($this->session->data['desired_service']==2){
    echo 'Take Away';
} else if ($this->session->data['desired_service']==3){
    echo 'DinIN';
}
```

Here is the code that I have used so far.

```
$service = ( $this->session->data['desired_service']== 1 ) ? "Home Delivery" : ( $this->session->data['desired_service'] == 2 ) ? "Take Away" : ( $this->session->data['desired_service'] == 3 ) ? "DinIN";
```

But it is giving me a syntax error.

Comment: I've only one thing to say: Don't. It makes your code unreadable and ugly.

Comment: Don't.... nested ternaries are non-intuitive, and hard to read.... if you do it now, you'll be cursing yourself in 6 weeks when you need to make a change to it

Comment: you can go for switch case but nesting ternary will hard to understand...

Comment: [If you absolutely have to nest ternaries, you need to get the brackets right](https://3v4l.org/JfSl5#tabs) but this isn't intuitive to read

Comment: I used if else but it was required to do it through ternary operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
echo ($this->session->data['desired_service'] == 3) ? 'DinIN' : (($this->session->data['desired_service']==1) ? 'Home Delivery' : ($this->session->data['desired_service'] == 2) ? 'Take Away' : '');
```

**Explanation:**

Use nested ternary operator.

```
If variable equal to 3, print 'DinIN'    
else : two cases:
if 1 : Home Delivery
else : Take Away
```

Demos:

[if value is 1](https://eval.in/461525)

[If value is 2](https://eval.in/461524)

[if value is 3](https://eval.in/461526)

**Another solution**

Use predefined array:

Get all your options in an array and add

1,2 and 3 as keys.

Check array with `isset` and the variable.

If it is set, print it, else blank.

Purpose solved.

```
<?php
$arr = array();
$arr[1] = 'Home Delivery';
$arr[2] = 'Take Away';
$arr[3] = 'DinIN';
echo isset($arr[$this->session->data['desired_service']]) ? $arr[$this->session->data['desired_service']] : '';
?>
```

Comment: I want the values to be only on 1,2 and 3. Any other value should yield empty value. Is that possible?

Comment: Answer updated, please check. It will work for your query.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks @Pupil

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good example of when to use ternary operators.  Personally, looking at your data - I would use a switch statement, as it will be easier to read and add more options to.

```
switch($this->session->data['desired_service']){

    case '1':
        $service = "Home Delivery";
        break;

    case '2':
        $service = "Take Away";
        break;

    case '3':
        $service = "DinIN";
        break;

}
```

Comment: The answer is always last option in every case. :(

Comment: Sadly, that wouldn’t work. The ternary operator is left associative in PHP, meaning this would evaluate “from right to left”. You’d have to use parantheses.

Comment: you are just little bit faster in switch than me  ... nice +1

Comment: @MarkBaker I agree - its UGLY, but if you add the brackets it does work: `$service = 
($desired_service == 1 ? "Home Delivery" : ($desired_service == 2 ? "Take Away" : ($desired_service == 3 ? "DinIN" :'')));`